# Applying regular expression on a pandas dataframe on each item in iteritem and return just the first part

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file which has name of states and universities. I have read it into a dataframe by using pandas.read_table(). I am then iterating through it by iterrows() and on each item I would like to get only the state and the university. States can be detected by [edit] suffix. The universities are then followed in other rows until the next state appears. Which means another name followed by "[edit]". A view of the dataframe is shown below:

[image]

As shown Alabama in row 0 is a state. The universities in rows 1 to 8 belong to Alabama until row 9 appears which is another state. Row 10 belongs to state in row 9, Alaska. The whole dataframe has this structure. I am trying to clean it and return another data frame with this structure: One column with name of states and universities together, but without the parts after [] and (). It would then look like the following:

Alabama

Auburn

Florence

Jacksonville

Some of the records have "." or white space in their names. I have written the following regular expression to get them but the result is giving me "edit", "Auburn University", etc. as well. In other words it is returning whatever that matches, not only the first part.

The code is as follows: I have read the txt file into a dataframe called df_university_town. I then applied regular expression as follows:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+[\.\s]?[a-zA-Z]+)(\w?)')
for key, item in df_university_town.iteritems():
    matches = pattern.finditer(str(item))
    for match in matches:
        print(match.group(1))
```

And this is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you see "edit" and "Auburn University" in the final result are extra. I used a different approach and tried match() as well, but that was also not helpful. Basically when I reach "[" or "(" search should not continue. I do not know what else I need to do. I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you very much for your help and the time you are putting into this.

Comment: Please replace your images with something we can copy/paste as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to grab everything before those characters, then use `.str.split`. The regex allows for optional whitespace character before the `(` or `[` so you don't need to strip that later.

```
df.RegStatName.str.split('(\s?\(|\s?\[)').str[0]

0      Alabama
1       Auburn
2     Florence
3       Alaska
4    Fairbanks
5      Arizona
6      Nothing
7         This
Name: RegStatName, dtype: object
```

#### Sample Data: `df`

```
                                     RegStatName
0                                  Alabama[edit]
1                  Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2         Florence (University of NOrth Alabama)
3                                   Alaska[edit]
4  Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
5                                  Arizona[edit]
6                                        Nothing
7                               This [something]
```

Comment: Thanks but actually the state and university should stay not to ffill the state instead of university.

Comment: @E.Erfan is that more in line with what you need?

Comment: no no, I am trying to get both states and exactly in the order of the txt file get the universities beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
([^\(\)\[\]\n\r]+)(?![^\[\(]*?[\]\)])
```

It does look simple, but it seems to work with your sample set, as you can see here: **https://regex101.com/r/jBSeqQ/2**

If you wanted the names of the universities separately, do mention so in the comments below :)

Comment: It is working but there is a little problem. It has inserted a lot of free spaces. I just replaced it the r-string. pattern = re.compile(r'([^\(\)\[\]\n\r]+)(?![^\[\(]*?[\]\)])'). Is there a way to get rid of the whitespaces?

Comment: Also it has injected a number at the beginning of each of the records!

Comment: @Coffehouse i think this is the correct approach that you mentioned, just the numbers and added space is the problem.